# Translation via custom labels for dynamically generated content

Tags: apex, visualforce, customlabel, translation

**The context.**

To dynamically translate custom labels in Apex for a given language that differ from the language of the current user, I use the [Visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/184453/apex-get-a-custom-label-translation-in-a-certain-language-which-is-not-equal-to) approach.

**The problem.**

I can't use this approach synchronously from a context trigger, due to a salesforce constraint: "The getContent PageReference method is not allowed in triggers." There is an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhbvUAB/allow-getcontent-to-be-called-from-a-trigger).
The only thing I could do is to mark the transaltion method as @future(Callout = true) so it can be invoked in triggers. Although this @future method executes quickly, there is no way I can force  the subsequent synchronous code to await until the @future method is executed. The integrity of the trigger transaction is of paramount importance.

**The questions.**

Is there any known mechanism or workaround to await execution of a @future method?

If no, is there any solution for syncrounous dymanic custom label translation in Apex, without callouts?

Please help me. Any tips are appreciated in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to translate the value in apex?

Comment: Custom labels store subjects and descriptions for dynamically generated tasks. I'm aware that I could store them in custom object records, but such a refactoring would require a lot of effort.

Comment: It is impossible to wait for futures. All asynchronous processes initiated in a transaction are not started until the transaction has successfully completed. This is necessary to ensure they only happen if the initiating transaction is successful.

Comment: (There is one exception, which is a publish immediately platform event which can be processed in an overlapping transaction.)

Comment: @PhilW I think youre right, thank you for the tip.